# dav2fs mount only works manually via 'sudo mount..', does NOT work via fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, webdav, nextcloud

I hope I'm in the correct stack exchange site here with this dav2fs question.

So anyway, lets get to it..

Running: Ubuntu 17.10

Trying to get dav2fs to mount my nextcloud storage as a fs.

I've copied the password file into the root location and the user location, just in case - `/etc/davfs2/secrets` and `~/.davfs2/secrets`

It works without a problem when mounting manually, with the following command:

`sudo mount -t davfs https://cloud.domain.xyz/remote.php/webdav/ /opt/ndo_cloud`

Now trying to add it to fstab to automount at boot with:

`https://cloud.domain.xyz/remote.php/webdav/ /opt/ndo_cloud davfs rw,user,uid=1000,noauto 0 0`

Unfortunately does not work - it just seems to skip over it - no error or anything via `sudo mount -a`.

I'd like to note that I've mounted this exact same nextcloud instance via this method on my work PC, my home PC, however is experiencing the above problem. I'd also like to mention that I have 2FA enabled on my nextcloud instance - so I created app passwords (separate ones for my work and home pc).

Answer (score 2):

Struggled the same way - and found the solution:

the "problem" was the `noauto` flag at the options-part of our fstab-entries.
This means, it gets skipped while running `sudo mount -a`.

(see [this question/answer over here](https://superuser.com/a/1038152))